# The best way to parse web-sql response

Tags: json, parsing, web-sql

What is the best way to parse web sql response db which is in browser(sqLite)?

```
function getBlockOfDataFromDb(minVal, qty) {
 db.transaction(function(tx) {
   tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Products WHERE id BETWEEN '+ minVal +' AND '+ (minVal+qty), [], function(tx, result) {
     result;
   });
 });
```

Now i have to convert data to json and work with it. So maybe anybody knows best practices for it?
I can get data like:

```
result.rows.item(0).id // => 1
result.rows.item(1).id // => 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose next solution:

```
function getBlockOfDataFromDb(minVal, qty) {
  var res = '{\"data\":[';
 db.transaction(function(tx) {
   tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM primeNumbers WHERE id BETWEEN '+ minVal +' AND '+ (minVal+qty - 1), [], function(tx, result) {
     result_length = result.rows.length;
     for(var i = 0; i < result_length; i++) {
       res += '{\"id\":\"'+result.rows.item(i).id+'\",\"value\":\"'+result.rows.item(i).value+'\"}';
       (i != result_length-1) && (res +=',');
     };
     res += ']}'
     return $.parseJSON(res);
   });
 });
};
```